# remove DeliveryAddress guard at checkout

Tags: spartacus-storefront

How do I remove DeliveryAddress guard at checkout?
I don't need to have DeliveryAddress set
I’m using Spartacus 4.0**strong text**

Answer (score 0):

You can remove a guard by overriding the default guards assigned to a component. As explained in here https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/extending-checkout/#extensibility, you can override the component's guard as follows

```
      cmsComponents: {
        InsertTheCmsComponentIdentifier: {
          component: InsertTheSpartacusComponent,
          guards: [InsertAnyGuard, InsertAnyGuard]
        },
      },
    })
```